# NodeJS error in node modules

Tags: node.js, webpack, package, node-modules

I have a project using **VueJS**, **Webpack** and some *JS Plugins*, like **Jquery Datatable**.
Everything goes well, i have a `package.json` where has all depedences.
 Here we a team with 10 developers. Not all of them work with this project, there are some developers that touch in this project every month. They already have all project, nothing changes with `package.json` dependences, but when i build the project, there are some strange errors in terminal, like not found some dependences(?) even all folders being there. Nothing changed with `node_modules` folder. If i delete it and run `npm install`, it works.
 The question is: **"Why does the folder `node_modules` "lose" the references when it is a long time without moving the object?"**

Thanks!

Comment: Well, node_modules should be excluded from version control and everyone should run an npm update. You have to compile native modules per machine. You can't just move node_modules around.

Comment: Hi @zfor, thanks for answer... So... I don't move `node_modules` folder, people here get the project folder instead of `node_modules` folder, because it is created when they run `npm install`... The problem is when they stay 15 days without opening the project, so when they open after a long time, in terminal they said that some dependenced was missed, but it was not, nothing changed in `node_modules` folder since last time they opened. Why is this happen?

Comment: Then I have no idea. Perhaps you should include error messages and/or your package.json file to get a little closer to the solution.